# Triggering 'next' frame in Niall Doherty's coda slider 2.0 - Possible using JavaScript .change event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, coda-slider

I've been driving myself crazy trying to make this work. Variations of my attempt have become insanely embarrassing - I just can't seem to figure out what Niall slider wants me to do in order to trigger the slider to go to the next frame without clicking anything.

What I want is for the slider to slide to the next frame when form elements are changed. So, with jQuery that should be about as simple as saying:

```
$(document).ready(function()  
 {  
  $('#radioButton').change(function(){  
   GO TO THE NEXT FRAME  
  });  
 })
```

But apparently it's not that simple. I've tried a lot of things. Some desperate things. Mostly just trying to trigger parts of his code. The code that appears to make the next frame happens is this code:

```
    $('#coda-nav-right-' + sliderCount + ' a').click(function(){
        navClicks++;
        if (currentPanel == panelCount) {
            offset = 0;
            currentPanel = 1;
            alterPanelHeight(0);
            slider.siblings('.coda-nav').find('a.current').removeClass('current').parents('ul').find('a:eq(0)').addClass('current');
        } else {
            offset = - (panelWidth*currentPanel);
            alterPanelHeight(currentPanel);
            currentPanel += 1;
            slider.siblings('.coda-nav').find('a.current').removeClass('current').parent().next().find('a').addClass('current');
        };
        $('.panel-container', slider).animate({ marginLeft: offset }, settings.slideEaseDuration, settings.slideEaseFunction);
        if (settings.crossLinking) { location.hash = currentPanel }; // Change the URL hash (cross-linking)
        return false;
    });
```

It's a combination of me being very mediocre with JavaScript and being fairly unfamiliar with Niall's code. It's well commented, but I can't tell exactly what's happening on each line. When I can see, I'm not really sure how to make the same thing happen with my `.change` function.

Anyway, if someone can shed some light on this I'd be incredibly grateful. I think if I can be helped to figure this out, it might help me out quite a bit down the line as well. I think there's something about JavaScript here that I'm not understanding, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically click a link using the no-args [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function in jQuery.  Assuming you are using the same setup as most of the examples, you should be able to write something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="next-panel" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#next-panel").bind("change", function() {
    $("#coda-nav-right-1 > a").click();
});
```

This will click the link that's in the default location for the "right" link in the demos.  You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/WzJMP/

**Side note:** Have you considered using [jQueryUI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation)? jQueryUI has a much more usable and well-documented API, and you could easily recreate the effects and functionality of Coda slider.  You'll also probably get better support on sites like StackOverflow.

Comment: Hey Andrew, your response is perfect! I understand how and why it works now as well. I really appreciate your help. Also, jQueryUI tabs would have been preferable, or writing something basic to do what I needed even, but someone else originally developed this project with the coda slider so I didn't have a choice.